# Way to trigger the traffic light in anylogic

Tags: anylogic, traffic-simulation

**AnyLogic** provides traditional traffic lights which are triggered on the **basis of time**. I am creating a **new** road traffic management system in which I want to **trigger** traffic lights on the basis of the **greatest** car density among the **four roads**. Is there any function or element that would help me to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to code it yourself.

That, however, is entirely possible. Just learn more about AnyLogic and how to write code, how to count cars on a road, how to manually switch traffic lights, etc.

Then, you can easily make it happen.

Comment: I agree to Benjamin. Here is a [blog post with code](https://florianhuebler.com/traffic-priorisation-in-anylogic/) (Disclosure: It is my own personal blog), on a fairly similar traffic situation in AnyLogic.